# Comprehensive summary of where the function $\pi^{-\frac x\pi}$ can be encountered

Tags: special-functions, exponential-function, riemann-zeta

I am studying the special functions, including the Riemann Xi and Zeta, and everywhere a function $\pi^{-\frac x\pi}$ pops up, usually as multiplier to the Gamma function. But yet I am not sure this function has any significance outside Zeta function studies.

I wonder what other interesting properties the exponent with the base $\frac {1}{\sqrt[\pi]{\pi}}$ can possess. Does it appear anywhere else?

Comment: Where does $\pi^{-x/\pi}$ arise as a multiplier to the Gamma function? The completed Riemann zeta function is $\pi^{-s/2} \Gamma(s/2) \zeta(s)$, and I don't know what this has to do with $\pi^{-x/\pi}$.